# Scala Swing equivalent of JPanel with null layout

Tags: swing, scala, layout, panel

I am writing a Swing application in Scala where I want explicit placement of Components by coordinates. In Java Swing, this is done by having the LayoutManager set to null, and then manually adding Components like so:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(null);
JLabel l = new JLabel("hi");
l.setLocation(3,3);
p.add(l);
```

I have seen several posts about Scala equivalents around the web all using solutions similar to this:

```
import scala.swing._

class NullPanel extends Panel {
  peer.setLayout(null)

   protected def add(comp: Component, x: Int, y: Int) {
     comp.peer.setBounds(new Rectangle(x,y,comp.bounds.width,comp.bounds.height))
     peer.add(comp.peer)
  }
}
```

If I use this class in an application like:

```
import scala.swing._

object Frame extends SimpleSwingApplication{
  val pan = new NullPanel {
    preferredSize = new Dimension(500,500)
    add(new Label("HI"),55,55)
  }

  def top = new MainFrame {
    contents = pan
  }
}
```

Intuitively, this should create a window with a 500 by 500 Panel containing a Label with the text "HI" at coordinates (55,55). However, when I run this, the panel is empty. What am I doing wrong here? How can I achieve a Panel class with arbitrary placement of contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout manager takes care of setting the children's dimensions. If you do not have a layout manager, components have their initial sizes which is normally `(0, 0)`. A workaround is to set the size to the component's preferred size. That implies that you have configured the component before, so the preferred size is correctly determined.

```
class NullPanel extends Panel {
  peer.setLayout(null)

  protected def add(comp: Component, x: Int, y: Int): Unit = {
    val p = comp.peer
    p.setLocation(x, y)
    p.setSize(p.getPreferredSize) // !
    peer.add(p)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Java and Scala code are not equivalent. To make it so, the Scala code should look like:

```
import scala.swing._

class NullPanel extends Panel {
  peer.setLayout(null)

   protected def add(comp: Component, x: Int, y: Int) {
     comp.peer.setLocation(x,y)
     peer.add(comp.peer)
  }
}
```

Another problem IMO is that you're setting width and height of component using it default  component bounds, which seems to be 0.